# Function with both easy to find Fourier and Hermitian coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm writing some notes on Spectral theory and I would like to make a simple example finding the generalized fourier coefficient of a function in respect of two different bases. I was thinking about Hermitian functions and the usual trigonometric functions, i.e. 
For the Hermitian series the coefficients are labelled $h_n$
\begin{equation} Hermitian: 
\psi_{n}\left(x\right)=\left(2^{n}n!\sqrt{\pi}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(x\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h_{n} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!\sqrt{\pi}}}\int_{-1}^{1}f\left(x\right)e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(x\right)dx.
\end{equation}

While for the Fourier are the $c_n$

\begin{equation}Fourier:
\varphi_{n}\left(x\right)=e^{i\pi nx}.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
c_{n}  =\int_{-1}^{1}f\left(x\right)e^{-i\pi nx}dx.
\end{equation}

I was thinking about some $L^2([-1,1])$ function. I tried the Gaussian to simplify the hermitian family but didn't work out. Can anybody suggest me something?